# HasRows is empty despite valid query and connection

Tags: c#, sql, .net

For some reason, HasRows is false despite the connection and query seeming valid. There is a record in the table.

There are no errors when opening the connection, so I assume it's valid.

I can't see why HasRows would be false.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Projects\app\app.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

string sql = @"SELECT * from SavedSettings";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader["ignoreCase"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    ignoreCase.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ignoreCase.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't always trust the `HasRows`. There are times when it has data but returns `false`. It's been a little wonky since it was introduced. Try this instead:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // Has rows.
}
else {
    // No row.
}
```

**OR** you don't even need to check `if (reader.HasRows)` anymore. If your table has no row, then the program will bypass the `while (reader.Read())` with no problem. Just use:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader["ignoreCase"].ToString() == "1")
    {
        ignoreCase.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ignoreCase.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Finally, restart Visual Studio and reconnected to the database then selected Show Table Data.

Comment: In the first example, I'm getting dt.Rows.Count as 0. I tried the second example previously. I just added HasRows to show that the result set was empty.

Comment: Try changing `string sql = @"SELECT * from SavedSettings";` to `string sql = @"select * from SavedSettings";`

Comment: I found the problem. It is a Visual Studio SQL editor issue. It said the table had records but it didn't. I reconnected to the database then selected Show Table Data and I'm now my changes are being committed. Maybe a copy is cached elsewhere? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow. Restarting, close-reopening and disconnect-reconnecting fix many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnected then reconnected to the database and opened the data viewer and it shows my changes. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Refreshing the database and refreshing the data viewer did nothing.

Incidentally, it's still not syncing (see below), and I have to keep connecting/reconnecting to see the changes. I'm going to use a different editor.

Before reconnecting (includeSubFolders field shows on left, not right):

[image: What I had]

After reconnecting:

[image: What I thought I had]